# Reading Data from a website and using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to take information from a site, read it in line by line and only take the lines that start with two digits, a semicolon, two digits a semicolon and two more digits (i.e. 00:00:00). Matches are exported to another file.

I am getting a syntax error for the semicolons in my regex.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2
import re

#imported urllib to collect the data. imported re for regular expressions to     test format.


#creating our output file
f=open("output.txt", "r+")

#opening a file like object using urllib
webpage= urllib2.open("https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf")


#string used to store the output
str=""

#string used to store current line
temp=""


#add while loop to read in that data. line by line. 
temp=webpage.readline()
if temp.re.search([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]):

  str.concat(temp)
  temp=""
```

Comment: You need to escape the colon by adding a \ infront of it. The colon is an operator in regex.

Comment: Since when, @blasko? The issue is just missing quotes (`""`) around the regex.

Comment: @JakeGriffin helping him with the problem he will encounter once he adds the quotes.

Comment: My point was that colons are not an operator in regex. `"[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]"` works just fine. Colons are only (part of) an operator in the `(?: ... )` syntax.

Comment: @blasko oh thanks! I also changed 
`code` f=open("output.txt", "r+") 
to w+
however, now I get the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 're'  from the if line.

Comment: Try changing `if temp.re.search([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]):` to `if re.search("[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]", temp):`

Comment: Also, it looks like you aren't just looking for strings of the form "##:##:##". That webpage has things like "3C:98:BF" as well.

Comment: @JakeGriffin Oh good catch. So I am looking to just use "\w\w:\w\w:\w\w". Does anybody know how to iterate through all the lines while there are lines? so replacing the basic for loop (which isn't successfully reading in any lines anyway!)

         `for i in (10,100):

             temp=webpage.readline(10)
             if re.search("\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", temp):
                str1+=temp

        f.write(str1)`

Answer (score 2):

You are searching using raw code, try inputting a string

```
if temp.re.search("[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]"):
```